# Edit Item in hasMany association (CakePHP)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables in Mysql:

1- Items

columns:  id, name, price, category_id, created

2- Categories

columns:  id, name, created

Categories has many Item and Items belongs to Category:

```
Class Item extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = 'Category';
}

lass Category extends AppModel {
   public $hasMany  = 'Item';
}
```

I would like to edit a given Item, therefore I would like to show the possible categories name to pick up one.

View/Items/edit.ctp

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Item');
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('price');
    echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('created');
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

Controller/ItemsController.php

```
public function edit($id = null){
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Item'));
        }
        $item = $this->Item->findById($id);

        if (!$item) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Item'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $item;
        }

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->Item->id = $id;
            if ($this->Item->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your item has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your item.'));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that: In category_id in the form I can't see anything even the category Id number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a `$categories` variable in the controller;

```
$this->set('categories', $this->Item->Category->find('list'));
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Assuming that User hasAndBelongsToMany Group. In your controller, set a camelCase plural variable (group -> groups in this case, or ExtraFunkyModel -> extraFunkyModels) with the select options. In the controller action you would put the following:

```
$this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
```

And in the view a multiple select can be created with this simple code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Group');
```

If you want to create a select field while using a belongsTo - or hasOne - Relation, you can add the following to your Users-controller (assuming your User belongsTo Group):

```
$this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
```

Afterwards, add the following to your form-view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
```